# Batch script that rename a file by appending a version

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo OFF
set CURR_DATE=%DATE%
set MONTH=%CURR_DATE:~4,2%
set DAY=%CURR_DATE:~7,2%
set YEAR=%CURR_DATE:~12,2%
set SEQ=%DAY%-1
set VERSION=%YEAR%%MONTH%%SEQ%

if exist "E2F.csv" (
  echo "File Exists, Renaming"
  rename "E2F.csv" E2F0%VERSION%.csv
) else (
  echo "File Not Found"
)

PAUSE
```

Any that can help? I need a script that will rename the `file E2F.cvs` to `E2F0YYMMSeq`.
Seq is equal to `day - 1`. The script above I don't know it is not renaming. Thank you.

Comment: does the script prints an error?Or `file not found` ?

Comment: What language is your system set to use? This is important since %DATE% will different results based on your reginal settings

Comment: What is the file currently being renamed to?

Comment: The program is return this error: "File Exists, Renaming"
The system cannot find the path specified. I am using windows 8.

Comment: ? Are you running the script from the folder where the file you want to rename is?

Comment: The file is saved as E2F.csv and I want to rename it to E2F0YYMMSQEQ. Where by SEQ=DAY-1. e.g. E2F0130519

Comment: Type `echo %version%`   and show the output here.

Comment: @Lamech - This is wrong: `set VERSION=5/0 `. There can't be a slash in the path or file name.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `SET /A SEQ=%DAy%-1` in stead of `SET SEQ=%DAy%-1` in order to make the calculation work.

Both the scipt and the E2F.csv file must be in the same folder as the script is now.

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder....! I @echo on and this is what I see: 
C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>set CURR_DATE=20/05/2013

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>set MONTH=5/

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>set DAY=01

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>set YEAR=

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>set /A SEQ=01-1

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>set VERSION=5/0

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>if exist "E2F.csv" (
echo "File Exists, Renaming"
 rename "E2F.csv" E2F05/0.csv
)  else (echo "File Not Found" )
"File Exists, Renaming"
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Lameck\Documents>PAUSE

Comment: The problem is that you get a `/` in your file name as @endoro mentions in the comment to your question. The system interprets that as a directory division. (yes, windows does that now a days.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set CURR_DATE=%DATE%  &REM date is 20/05/2013
set "MONTH=%CURR_DATE:~3,2%"
set "DAY=%CURR_DATE:~0,2%"
set "YEAR=%CURR_DATE:~8,2%"
set /a SEQ=1%DAY%-101
set "VERSION=%YEAR%%MONTH%%SEQ%"

if exist "E2F.csv" (
echo "File Exists, Renaming"
rename "E2F.csv" "E2F0%VERSION%.csv"
) else (
echo "File Not Found"
)
```

If you calculate `SEQ=DAY-1` the result will be sometimes `0`.

Comment: This script works on my machine. @lamech is this still not working for you?